# E11000 duplicate key error collection error (Doesn't make any sense)

Tags: javascript, angular, database, mongodb, express

So I have a users collection from which I authenticate users, It worked at start, but when I provided messaging function in my app, I had to provide socketId field in mongoose which would be an empty string at the start, but when a user logged in, each user would get a socketId field.

The main problem is that when I sign up (WHERE SOCKETID IS SET AS ''), no errors occur and a new user is added, but when I try to sign up the second time E11000 error occurs and says that there are duplicate keys, but (Remember, I just set socketId as an empty string on signup, I set real socket id on login)

1. SocketId field is not required or unique;
2. It was called socketId, but now I renamed it as 'sId' and set sId --EVERYWHERE-- the error still says that problem is with socketId
3. I tried to remove socketId from the mongoose schema and everywhere it was, but the error with socketId was still there

Server, where I export socketId after connection
`

```
let socketID;

const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
    }
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socketID = socket.id;
    exports.sId = socketID;
)
```

`
Auth mongoose :

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    nickname: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    sId: {type: String, unique: false},
    afterLogin: {type: Object, required: true},
});
```

Auth sign up

```
router.post('', (req, res, cb) => {
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
    .then(hash => {
        let userC = new User({
            email: req.body.email,
            nickname: req.body.nickname,
            password: hash,
            sId: '',
            afterLogin: req.body.afterLogin
        })
        .save().then((user) => {
            res.status(200).json({
                user
            })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            res.status(500).json({
                message: 'There is a user with same email or nickname'
            });
        })
    })
});
```

If you need the login code I'll provide it, but the main problem now occurs on singing up;

Comment: You have an `unique` index on the `socketId` field in the collection that you will need to manually drop

Comment: Can you please let me know what a unique index means or how can I drop a collection? Because I tried Users.drop() which didn't work , and if I drop a collection will I be able to acces it again?

Comment: Login to mongodb shell and do db.users.dropIndex("socketId")

Comment: Does the documentation for [unique indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/core/index-unique/), [getIndexes()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.getIndexes/), and [dropIndex()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/) (like @BrijeshDave mentioned) help? I don't think you want to drop the collection as that removes all of the data.